# Send data from loop created input fields in view to mvc controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a view with different fields in a loop. Depending on the model it should create as much fields as counts for the loop. Here a example for the page:

```
 _________     ___________     _________
|CONNECTOR|   |SEARCHINPUT|   |Selection|
|_________|   |___________|   |_________|
 ________________      ________________
|Add Search Field|    |Sub Search Field|
|_B_U_T_T_O_N____|    |_B_U_T_T_O_N____|
```

The View class looks like:

```
@model Modelle.Models.SearchModel
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < (int)Model.SearchCount; i++)
    {  <tr>
        <th>@if (i > 0)
            {<select name="ConnectorList" id="ConnectorList">
            <option value="AND" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("AND") ? "selected" : "")>AND</option>
            <option value="OR" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("OR") ? "selected" : "") >OR</option>
            <option value="NAND" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("NAND") ? "selected" : "") >NAND</option>
            <option value="NOR" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("NOR") ? "selected" : "") >NOR</option>
        </select>}
        </th>
        <th>
            <input name="SearchInput" id="SearchInput" type="text" value="@(Model.SearchList.ElementAt(i) as String)" /></th>
        <th>
            <select name="SelectionList" id="SelectionList">
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.SelectedList.Count(); j++)
                {<option value="@j" @(Model.Selection.ElementAt(i).Equals(j) ? "selected" : "")>@(Model.SelectedList.ElementAt(j).Name as String)</option> 
                }
            </select>
        </th>
    </tr>}

</table>
<p>
    <button name="button" type="button" onclick="AddSearchField()">Add one more search field</button>
    <button name="button" type="button" onclick="SubSearchField()">Remove one search field</button>
```

Here the jquery code for the buttons:

```
function AddSearchField() {
    var value1 = $('#SearchInput').val();
    var value2 = $('#SelectionList').val();
    var value3 = $('#ConnectorList').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AddSearchField", "Search")",
        type: 'POST',
        chache:false,
        data: 'searchInput=' + value1 + '&selectionList=' + value2 + '&connectorList=' + value3,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#OpenSearchInput').html(response);
            },
   });
    }
    function SubSearchField() {
        var value1 = $('#SearchInput').val();
        var value2 = $('#SelectionList').val();
        var value3 = $('#ConnectorList').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SubSearchField", "Search")",
            type: 'POST',
            chache: false,
            data: 'searchInput=' + value1 + '&selectionList=' + value2 + '&connectorList=' + value3,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#OpenSearchInput').html(response);
            },
        });
}
```

And the controller code:

```
public PartialViewResult AddSearchField(List<String> searchInput, List<int> selectionList, List<String> connectorList)
        {
            SearchModel searchModel = new SearchModel();
            if (connectorList == null)
            {
                connectorList = new List<String>();
            }
            searchModel.ConnectorList = connectorList;
            searchModel.Selection = selectionList.ToList();          
            searchModel.SelectedList = setSearchFields();
            List<String> searchList = new List<String>();
            int row = searchInput.Count();
            searchModel.SearchList = searchInput.ToList();
            searchModel.SearchList.Add("search");
            searchModel.SearchCount = row + 1;
            searchModel.ConnectorList.Add("AND");
            searchModel.Selection.Add(0);
            return PartialView("SearchInput", searchModel);
        }
        public PartialViewResult SubSearchField(List<String> searchInput, List<int> selectionList, List<String> connectorList)
        {
            SearchModel searchModel = new SearchModel();
            if (connectorList == null)
            {
                connectorList = new List<String>();
            }
            searchModel.ConnectorList = connectorList;
            searchModel.Selection = selectionList.ToList();          
            searchModel.SelectedList = setSearchFields();
            List<String> searchList = new List<String>();
        int row = searchInput.Count();
        searchModel.SearchList = searchInput.ToList();
        if (searchInput.Count() > 1)
        {
            searchModel.SearchList.RemoveAt(searchInput.Count() - 1);
            searchModel.SearchCount = row - 1;
            searchModel.ConnectorList.RemoveAt(connectorList.Count() - 1);
            searchModel.Selection.RemoveAt(selectionList.Count() - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            searchModel.SearchCount = row;
        }
        return PartialView("SearchInput", searchModel);
    }
```

If i load the page normally it has one search line. If i press the button "add one more search field" it added one line. If i click it a second time nothing happens. If i click the "Remove one search field button (anytime) the second fields disappear. In the debug mode, i can see that in the controller everytime the lists just count 1.

Did someone know where i´m mistaken?
Know anybody a easier way to add the lines? I have to send all the inputs later to the controler to search in a database with different rules depending on the inputs.

Comment: Try wrap the entire thing in a form and then sending $('#theForm').serialize() as the data of your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
<input name="SearchInput" id="SearchInput" type="text" value="@(Model.SearchList.ElementAt(i) as String)" />
```

and all other form elements as well in a for loop.

therefore in DOM, you are rendering multiple fields with same ids('SearchInput','ConnectorList','SelectionList')

`var value1 = $('#SearchInput').val();` assigns only one string value to value1,

`data: 'searchInput=' + value1`
 here value1 will have only one stirng.

remove Ids for form elements
change your ajax call as

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SubSearchField", "Search")",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#the form tag id').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#OpenSearchInput').html(response);
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i got already a form around for the search request but i don´t mentioned i could use it for this problem to, cause it would need different buttons to call different methods. A litte workaround from Andrey Shchekin safed my day (http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/ ) so i could use this form to solve my problem.
The view class now looks like:

```
@model Modelle.Models.SearchModel
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < (int)Model.SearchCount; i++)
    {  <tr>
        <th>@if (i > 0)
            {<select name="ConnectorList" id="ConnectorList">
            <option value="AND" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("AND") ? "selected" : "")>AND</option>
            <option value="OR" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("OR") ? "selected" : "") >OR</option>
            <option value="NAND" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("NAND") ? "selected" : "") >NAND</option>
            <option value="NOR" @(Model.ConnectorList.ElementAt(i - 1).Equals("NOR") ? "selected" : "") >NOR</option>
        </select>}
        </th>
        <th>
            <input name="SearchInput" id="SearchInput" value="@(Model.SearchList.ElementAt(i) as String)" /></th>
        <th>
            <select name="SelectionList" id="SelectionList">
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.SelectedList.Count(); j++)
                {<option value="@j" @(Model.Selection.ElementAt(i).Equals(j) ? "selected" : "")>@(Model.SelectedList.ElementAt(j).Name as String)</option> 
                }
            </select>
        </th>
    </tr>}

</table>
<p>
    <button name="AddSearchField" type="submit">Add one more search field</button>
    <button name="SubSearchField" type="submit"">Remove one search field</button>
```

And the View with the form above:

```
@model Tumormodelle.Models.SearchModel
<h2>Search Request</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend id="SearchInputHeadline">Here you can Search for all accessible TumorModels</legend>
    <b>@ViewBag.Message2 </b>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post"}, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
    {      
                 Html.RenderPartial("SearchFields");
                Html.RenderPartial("SearchFilter");
    <p>
            <button name="SearchForTumorModels" class="submitSearchForm" value="OpenSearchOutput" type="submit">Search for tumor models</button>
            <button name="button" type="submit">Clear the search form</button>
    </p>}
</fieldset>
```

In this way i don´t need any jquery but a new class to handle the different buttons and redirect them to the right methods:

```
 public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;

            if (!actionName.Equals("Action", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return false;

            var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
        }
    }
```

Last but not least i have to put `[HttpParamAction] [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` to the methods in the controller.
The main problem is solved now but it remains a little new problem. Depending on the button it should render the response in different `div`'s.